# Properly uninstall microphone and camera on Dell Inspiron

Tags: dell-inspiron, webcam, microphone

I have a Dell Inspiron, not entirely sure the model but it has the i7 core, 16GB RAM, 1TB storage and quad core.

Camera:

I've been trying to uninstall the camera but every time I uninstall the driver, exit device manager and then return to the manger, it has been reinstalled. I can disable the driver and that appears to prevent it from working but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Microphone:

The microphone when listen is turned off still  picks up sound. In fact, if I set it to listen the audio plays back which interferes with the mic and half repeats everything. I need the microphone but would prefer it wasn't listening all the time.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Right click >Disable the Camera in device manager, no  need to uninstall the driver. Right click >Disable the microphone in Control Panel >Sound >Recording Tab.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have managed to disable the driver for the camera but it turns back on occasionally. The microphone disable button when off still picks up sound and when it's on it plays it back through the speakers.

Comment: Disabled the device in device manager?